# Replace value of COL A with value of COL B based on a file containing the mapping

Tags: python, pandas

I have a .csv file read in as a Dataframe A containing the following:

```
COL_A   COL_B   COL_C   COL_D   
123     er      uy       rt  
234     we      fdg      gf  
212     tyt     jh       grf
```

I have another .csv file read in as a Dataframe B containing the following:

```
Replace_this    With_this  
COL_B           COL_D  
COL_C           COL_A
```

I want this result Dataframe C as:

```
COL_A   COL_B   COL_C   COL_D  
123     rt      123     rt  
234     gf      234     gf  
212     grf     212     grf
```

Notice that the values of COL_B and COL_C were replaced by the values from COL_D and COL_A respectively in Dataframe A based on the information in Dataframe B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
df.loc[:,df1.Replace_this]=df.loc[:,df1.With_this].values
print(df)
```

---

```
   COL_A COL_B  COL_C COL_D
0    123    rt    123    rt
1    234    gf    234    gf
2    212   grf    212   grf
```

Comment: Thanks. That works. I am new to python programming and wasn't aware of the .loc method within Pandas. It is definitely very powerful after I read the documentation.